# Why should we use condition and what's the differrence between Blocked and Waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, conditional-statements

There is an example in the book 'Core Java', it transfer money from one account to another. I don't know what is the usefulness of a condition? In the book, it tells us:

> if we just lock and wait without condition, it gets a deadlock:

```
private final double[] accounts;
private Lock bankLock;
private Condition sufficientFunds;

public void transfer(int from, int to, int amount) {
    bankLock.lock();
    try { 
        while (accounts[from] < amount) {
            // wait...
        }
        // transfer funds . . . 
    } finally { 
        bankLock.unlock(); 
    }
}
```

> Now, what do we do when there is not enough money in the account? We
>   wait until some other thread has added funds. But this thread has just
>   gained exclusive access to the `bankLock`, so no other thread has a
>   chance to make a deposit.
>
> When call

```
sufficientFunds.await();
```

> the current thread is now deactivated and gives up the lock. This lets
>   in another thread that can, we hope, increase the account balance.

`Lock` locks the code, and condition gives up the lock, but i don't know what is condition, why not just simple unlock the block when money is not enough?
And what's the difference between the thread state Blocked and Waiting?
block: the thread can not run;
waiting: the thread can not run too.
What is different?

another question:

```
while (accounts[from] < amount) {
   ...
   sufficientFunds.await();
```

Why not write `if`?

```
if (accounts[from] < amount) {
    ...
```

Comment: Only ask one question in a question. If you have two questions, create two questions. It's not possible to determine what is a good answer if you have multiple questions in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a particular requirement to the class `Bank`: if it's asked to transfer an amount of money from one account to another and there's not enough money on the source account, it must wait until enough money is deposited to make the transfer possible. You could run a loop that checks if it's enough money on every iteration and acquires the lock only when this condition is met:

```
while (true) {
    if (accounts[from] >= amount) {
        bankLock.lock();
        try {
            if (account[from] >= amount) {
                // do the transfer here...
                break;
            }
        } finally {
            bankLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

But this approach:

- squanders the CPU resources on constant checks (what it nobody
  deposits enough money in hours or days?)
- looks bulky and not idiomatic
- doesn't always work (the reason is out of the scope of this question, I can give a link to the explanation in the comments if you're interested in it)

So, you need some mechanism that tells that you're just waiting for some change in the account. It's wasteful to check the amount of money in an account again and again if nobody deposits money into it. And there's more – you also need to acquire the lock as soon as someone has deposited money, so you could exclusively check the new account state and make the decision on whether you can make your transfer or not.

You must also keep in mind, that deposit is not the only operation allowed on the account. There're also withdrawals, for instance. If someone made a withdrawal, there's no need to check your account on the possibility of transfer because we know for sure that it's even less money now. So, we want to be awaken on deposits but don't want to be awaken on the withdrawals. We need to separate them somehow. This is where conditions come to play.

Condition is an object implementing the `Condition` interface. It's just an abstraction that allows you to divide your lock/wait logic into parts. In our case, we could have two conditions: one for increasing of an account balance, another for decreasing (for instance, if someone is waiting of zeroing the bank account to close it):

```
sufficientFunds = bankLock.newCondition();
decreasedFunds = bankLock.newCondition();
```

Now, you don't need to make bazillion of checks in the loop, you can organise your program the way that allows you to only awake and check the account when someone funds an account:

```
private final double[] accounts;
private Lock bankLock;
private Condition sufficientFunds;

public void transfer(int from, int to, int amount) {
    bankLock.lock();
    try { 
        while (accounts[from] < amount) {
            sufficientFunds.await();
        }
        // transfer funds ...
        sufficientFunds.signalAll();
    } finally { 
        bankLock.unlock(); 
    }
}

public void deposit(int to, int amount) {
    bankLock.lock();
    try {
        // deposit funds...
        sufficientFunds.signalAll();
    } finally {
        bankLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

So, lets have a look at what's happening here and answer your questions:

1. `transfer()` is trying to acquire the `bankLock`. If someone already holds this lock, your thread becomes *blocked* by another thread until the lock is released.
2. When another thread releases the lock, you acquire it and can check the state of the account. If it's not enough money on it, you decide to sit and wait for someone to put money into the account, so you call `sufficienFunds.await()`. It makes your thread *waiting* for something to happen. You decided to do that, not just was blocked because of another thread, and that's the difference between *blocked* and *waiting*. But you're right, in both cases your thread is not running, so the difference is more logical, not technical.
3. Calling `await()` on a condition that was created on the `bankLock` releases this lock and makes it available to other threads to acquire and perform operations. Without releasing the lock, your thread would block all the operations in the bank and lead to a deadlock.
4. Now, when someone makes any change on the account that increases an amount of money, it notifies the `sufficientFunds` condition, our transferring thread awakes and the loop can make another check. Here we have two things to look at. First, when our thread awakes, it automatically reacquires the lock, so we can be sure that we can make checks and modifications exclusively and safely. Second, it might occur that the new amount of money is still not enough to make the transfer (signalling on a condition only means that something has happened that might change the state you're waiting for, but doesn't guarantee that state). In this case, we must wait for the next deposit. That's why we must use a `while` loop, not a simple `if`.
5. When finally the amount of money in the account is enough, we make our transfer. And we also call `sufficienFunds.signalAll()` after making transfer because we've increased the amount of money in the `to` account. If some other thread is waiting for this account to be funded, it acquires the lock and can make its work.

So, using locks and conditions allows you to organise your multithread program in a safe and efficient manner.

Comment: Thanks a lot,And i want to have a look at the linked page about  why use lock instead of condition doesn`t always work.     "doesn't always work (the reason is out of the scope of this question, I can give a link to the explanation in the comments if you're interested in it)"   @Andrew Lygin

Comment: My comment was about the double-check pattern I used in my first code snippet. In some cases it might break: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case was taken by the example of `synchronized` and  altered(for latest book revision, but of course not with out mistakes) the use of `Lock`. For such code with `synchronized` there is no questions:

```
   private final double[] accounts;
   private Condition sufficientFunds;
    public synchronized void transfer(int from, int to, int amount)
    {
         try { 
            while (accounts[from] < amount) {
            // wait . . . } 
        // transfer funds . . . 
         } finally {
            this.notifyAll();
         }
    }
```

When we call this method we acquire a lock, but when we call `wait()` we release it and become waiting for `notifyAll()` method called or specified time is out. After wake up we try again to acquire a lock and check our condition again.. and repeat this sequence of actions until we get enough money.

---

This picture shows you a difference between WAITING and BLOCKED:
[image]

---

Here we use

```
while (accounts[from] < amount) {
```

instead of

```
if (accounts[from] < amount) {
```

because we have want to get a positive result of method call, but we have no guarantee that another thread give all missing money to account we expected for. 
For example if you are a bank you call

reduce(John, 1000)

But client John has not enough money(500$ instead of 1000$) and if your reduce action wrapped in `if` instead of `while` you will attempt to wait only once. You was not lucky and at this time there was not clients in bank. So you come into `if`-block wait sometime and get lock again, but the amount of money on your account was not change(still 500$). You don't perform repeated check (because of if-block instead of while) and you go to transfer operation, which is almost not we really want.

---

Method `sufficientFunds.await();` have to do three operations in it: releaseLock(), wait(), lock(). This means we release lock to allow another thread to work with bank and wait it finished it operation, after that we acquire lock to perform check of our balance again and to make planned `transfer()` if we now get enough money.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all the reason for the while block**:

The code inside it is just to wait the thread at that line. The loop is only written so that when the thread is notified in the future (through any mechanism such as the thread that has added funds and used notifyAll after that), it checks for the condition again given in the while loop. If the amount is still greater that the accounts, it will again enter the wait condition and will leave the lock.
This will allow other threads to add funds and then again give the above thread in concern to have a shot on the while condition.
Once the while condition fails, it will not wait and will proceed to transfer the funds. Hence, will leave the lock through unblock condition.

**Difference between Blocked and Waiting:**

If we concentrate on using Waiting properly, we could avoid a condition known as Blocked. When we wait, we consider that the code is written in a way that the threads will notify each other properly without creating a deadlock.
If thread1 is waiting on a condition dependent on thread2 and thread2 is waiting on a condition depending on thread1, deadlock or block occurs.